# agGrid ng2 show blank rows instead of overlayNoRowsTemplate

Tags: angular, ag-grid-ng2

I have used ag-grid-ng2. i want to show blank rows by default instead of overlayNoRowsTemplate.
 How can i show blank rows by default (for example 10 blank rows).

Answer (score 1):

Before assigning the row data property to the grid, check to see if it's an empty array.  If it is, then make a new array containing 10 objects with the "shape" (or properties) as the objects that would have been in the array that came back empty (or at least with the properties that your column definitions are looking for).  Then assign each of the properties of each of the array elements you made a value of empty string (`""`) and feed that new array to the grid.